# syntax error line 29 in java script/ jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm just getting started learning some java script/ jquery. My function might be completely wrong but I can't even get it to compile to check it. (using firefox firebug debugger) I've looked at other code that's similar to what I'm trying to write and can't seem to get this syntax error out of the way to even see if it's going to even be close. If someone could help me figure this out I'd greatly appreciate it! Here's my code.

JavaScript Document:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    jQuery.fn.timer = function () {
        var $quote = $('#quote').children;
        var i = ('$quote p').css('display', ':visible');
        $quote.eq(i).animate({
            opacity: 0
        }, 300).css('display', ':none');

        if (i > $quote.length) {
            i = 0;
            $quote.eq(i).css('display', ':visible').animate({
                opacity: 100
            }, 300);

        } else {
            $quote.eq(i + 1).css('display', ':visible').animate({
                opacity: 100
            }, 300);
        }


        window.setInterval(function () {
            $('#quote').timer();
        }, 5000);

    });
})(); (edit)
```

edit: sorry the ":" was a typo here on the the forum, there really is a ";" at the end. I tried changing my code around this area many times but still get the same syntax error. Line 29 is the line above my edit.

Comment: The very last symbol should be a `;`, not a `:`.

Comment: Can you tell us which line refers to no.29 in your code

Comment: your code is expecting missing parenthesis ")"

Comment: Regarding `('$quote p').css('display', ':visible');`, if you want to use an existing selection as start point, you can use `.find`: `var $quote = $('#quote').children(); var i = $quote.find('p').css('display', ':visible');`. Spend some time browsing through the jQuery API documentation, it's worth it: http://api.jquery.com/. So, apart from syntax errors, you also have logical errors, which you can solve by reading the documentation.

Comment: @ felix kling, thanks for the input. I have looked at the documentation. I am also following a 30 day learn jquery video tut. I also know that there are logic errors, but I can't even get to those without first fixing the syntax error.

Answer (score 2):

The line `var i = ('$quote p').css('display', ':visible');` looks to be missing a `$` before the `('$quote p')` part.

**EDIT**

Also that line should surely be `$('#quote p')`?

**EDIT EDIT**

Also, as DCoder says in the comments, the last character should be a `;` not a `:`.

Comment: I think the `('$quote p')` refers to the `$quote` variable, and should actually be `$quote.find('p')`, assuming that `.children` is actually called in the previous line and not just referenced.

Comment: @felixkling $quote.find('p') is probably what I want there, thanks!

Comment: Feel free to mark this as correct if it helped find the solution.

Answer (score -1):

I think you was issue with missing paranthesis. Please see if below code helps you

```
$(document).ready(function () {

jQuery.fn.timer = function () {
    var $quote = $('#quote').children;
    var i = ('$quote p').css('display', ':visible');
    $quote.eq(i).animate({
        opacity: 0
    }, 300).css('display', ':none');

    if (i > $quote.length) {
        i = 0;
        $quote.eq(i).css('display', ':visible').animate({
            opacity: 100
        }, 300);

    } else {
        $quote.eq(i + 1).css('display', ':visible').animate({
            opacity: 100
        }, 300);
    }


    window.setInterval(function () {
        $('#quote').timer();
    }, 5000);

 };
```

});

Comment: Please someone tell reason for downvoting.